# Tree shakable icon component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, webpack, tree-shaking

I am creating a custom design system on top of [ChakraUI](https://chakra-ui.com/) and bootstrap icons.

Bootstrap icons contains 1000+ svg icons.
I created an abstract `Icon` component to have abstraction over the icon name, that seems IMO more convenient.

However, I am not sure this module will be tree-shaked, and I can't figure out how to change the implementation to make it tree-shakable.

#### Icon.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import * as bootstrapIcons from '@emotion-icons/bootstrap'

// Union of all icon names: 'Alarm' | 'Circle' | 'Square' ...
type IconNames = keyof typeof bootstrapIcons

export const Icon: FC<{name: IconNames}> = ({name}) => {
  const Icon = bootstrapIcons[name]

  return (
    <div>
      <Icon style={{...}} />
    </div>

  )
}
```

#### App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Icon } from './Icon'

const App = () => {
  return <div>
    <Icon name="Alarm" />
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Astrix imports cannot be tree shaken.

Generally when it comes to Icons you can have a Sprite Sheet or Tree Shaking but not both.

To make this particular library tree shake out icons you'll have to change your imports and usage to look like this (haven't tested but should work).

```
import { Alarm } from '@emotion-icons/bootstrap/Alarm';

const Use = () => <Alarm/>
```

There's definitely a caveat here where it would be possible to build a build-time plugin that changes...

```
<Icon name="Alarm"/>
 // to.
import { Alarm } from '@emotion-icons/bootstrap/Alarm';
<Alarm/>
```

and removes the import.

The reason why astrix imports can't be tree shaken is because javascript is a very dynamic language and static analysis of which keys are used is sometimes very difficult.

Consider the following code

```
import * as bootstrapIcons from '@emotion-icons/bootstrap'

bootstrapIcons["mralA".reverse()] // which icons should be tree shaken?
const Icons = new Proxy(bootstrapIcons) // which icons should be included? using proxy traps.
const SubSet = PullSubset(bootstrapIcons) // which icons should be included? no matter what the implementation of PullSubset is it will be impossible to preform static analysis on it to determine which icons have been used.
```

Comment: You example will work, but then I will lose the abstraction on top of icons. This abstraction allow me to only apply specific brand colors to icons..

An idea, would be to do something like this:
`<Icon icon={Alarm} color="blue" />` - However this approach is not convenient, because I will not have Icon props constraint with typescript, and I need to import specific icons each time I need to use Icon

Comment: You'll need to find another way to achieve this abstraction because again static analysis cannot tree shake this import pattern. One solution could be to import explicitly each Icon you're using into Icon.tsx an every time you need a new Icon add a new import statement to Icon.tsx

Comment: I see your point.

What if I write the following:
`import { Alarm } from '@emotion-icons/bootstrap'`
`import { Icon } from '../Icon'`

`const App = () => {
  return <Icon icon={Alarm} color="blue" />
}`
- Sorry for indent..

Comment: The behavior here is outside the scope of a single comment, but almost always again this wont tree shake, yes its not using astrix however commonjs dictates that the second you import a file all the exports that live in that file will end up in your bundle. There are some caveats to this but they are unlikely to apply here. https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ with the phrase "Ensure no compilers transform your ES2015 module syntax into CommonJS modules"